# How to get error count from logs for last x hour

Tags: datetime, go, time

I am trying to parse a log file to get errors count in the past X hours.

```
192.168.0.1 - - [11/Feb/2021:06:42:16 +0000] "POST /a/b/c/d/e HTTP/1.1" 200 28 "-" "-" 9104144117 "example" "http://example:8080" 102ms
192.168.0.1 - - [11/Feb/2021:11:42:16 +0000] "POST /a/b/c/d/e HTTP/1.1" 200 28 "-" "-" 9104144155 "example" "http://example2:8080" 91ms
192.168.0.1 - - [11/Feb/2021:12:42:16 +0000] "POST /a/b/c/d/e HTTP/1.1" 200 28 "-" "-" 9104144155 "example" "http://example3:8080" 91ms
```

Output:

```
200 2 http://example:8080
400 3 http://example2:8080
500 10 http://example:8080
```

I want the difference between the current time and X hours of the time in the log file. So, that I can get the errors in the last hour.

I tried using [time.Parse()](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#example_Parse) but it didn't accept the [date format](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#pkg-constants) as mentioned in the log file.

Is it a good idea to convert the logline time to a specific format like mentioned here https://golang.org/pkg/time/#pkg-constants or should I convert it to a duration?

This code is giving the wrong information. Because the format is not right.

```
    then, _ := time.Parse("01-JAN-1970 00:00:00", "11-Feb-2021 11:42:16")
    fmt.Println(then)
    lTime := then.Add(-1 * time.Hour) 
    fmt.Println(lTime)
```

Comment: you have to vrite your own parser, or at least is seems like, but if you care only about one hour difference you can omit ewerithing except 00:00:00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So for your time.Parse(...) when you specify the format in the first parameter, you have to use VERY specific values.

(Apologies, I don't know where in the docs this is located, I just always go to the source code when I need to reference it) https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/time/format.go#L92

So for you:

`"01-JAN-1970 00:00:00"` should be `"01-Jan-2006 03:04:05"`

Example using the correct format constant values from the given reference. https://play.golang.org/p/MUNqaFQHjVJ

EDIT:

For emphasis using the format.go reference, that is just the values (being month, hour, second, etc.) the syntax "01/Jan/2006" or "01-Jan-2006" or "01--Jan--2006" would all be valid ways of parsing times.

Go allows great flexibility of *how* string based dates are parsed.

Here's a further example with the format being `"01/Jan/2006 03:04:05"`: https://play.golang.org/p/kEyZEDpu-6N

Comment: does not work on my machine, is shows month out of range

Comment: It runs on my machine and on Go Playground. Can you put what you're running in Playground and share it?

Comment: The current string I am getting is `11/Feb/2021`. Do you want me to structure this to `11-FEB-2021`? Will it accept this format?

Comment: I'll update my answer with more detail, but the gist of it is that you'd use: `time.Parse("01/Jan/2006 03:04:05", "11/Feb-2021 11:42:16")`